# Wireless lost ability to use 5GHz (PCE-AC68)

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.10, asus

PCE-AC68 Dual-Band Wireless-AC1900 PCI-E Adapter, Ubuntu 15.10 fully updated.

Bought this sometime last year, installed and using some online resources managed to activate full 802.11ac speed (so not remember what the steps were, but it was not complicated).

I'm connecting to a router that has both 5GHz and 2.4GHz.

Worked well for a few months but since a while back 5GHz is not shown in the list, nor can I add it, even by manually specifying the SSID. Phone and Tablet continue to use 5GHz as before, so it's still there.

Tried all the reboots and so on and forth I could think of.

Ran the wireless.txt script, and in that I can see 5GHz channels, and some more info, though I can't really interpret the results.

Any idea what this could be / please help by looking at my config. :)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 23 Mar 2016 18:47 CET +0100

Booted last: 23 Mar 2016 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7798]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85df]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6365184  0
cfg80211              548864  1 wl

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.10.159  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'enp3s0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9351074 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5328393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12412445856 (12.4 GB)  TX bytes:989123585 (989.1 MB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:10391
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan bredbandsbolaget.se

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       686     1  0 Mar21 ?        00:00:31 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4157669e-a3a6-44a8-a2ef-c1f46b2639b8
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{5}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4157669e-a3a6-44a8-a2ef-c1f46b2639b8 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.10.159/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.10.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.10.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.10.159
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.10.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 35906
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 19706
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = lan
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1458794102
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = kristoffer-homebuntu
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.10.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 43200
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'enp3s0' [IF]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.DOMAIN[1]:                          lan
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_info_refresh_time = 600
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:af:bc:5f:4b:b8:12:b0:62:d5:51:9e:7c:19:ae:ca:8f
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = bredbandsbolaget.se.
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:<MAC address>
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp6_inf_max_rt = 60

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{4,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d7340ea8-c867-4151-8c6b-3de8eeabaa48 | ComHem<AF499A>
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   dcfeebac-4020-4cc1-88c1-9d1ade5aa9f3 | TN_24GHz_5C8941 1

SSID                           BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
TN_24GHz_5C8941                <MAC 'TN_24GHz_5C8941' [AC1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
ComHem<AF499A>                 <MAC 'ComHem<AF499A>' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
3Webbkontakt-E0E4              <MAC '3Webbkontakt-E0E4' [AC3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Pretty fly for a Wi-Fi         <MAC 'Pretty fly for a Wi-Fi' [AC5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA2       no        
TN_private_969E22              <MAC 'TN_private_969E22' [AC6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
TeliaGateway30-91-8F-2C-E4-53  <MAC 'TeliaGateway30-91-8F-2C-E4-53' [AC4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TN_24GHz_5C8941]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TN_24GHz_5C8941 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TN_24GHz_5C8941
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TN_private_A29775]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TN_private_A29775 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TN_private_A29775
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ComHem<AF499A>]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ComHem<AF499A> | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ComHem<AF499A>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TN_24GHz_5C8941 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TN_24GHz_5C8941 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TN_24GHz_5C8941
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TN_5GHz_5C8941]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TN_5GHz_5C8941 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp4s0' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TN_5GHz_5C8941
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Stockholm (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp4s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 50 : 5.25 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlp4s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'TN_24GHz_5C8941' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TN_24GHz_5C8941"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'ComHem<AF499A>' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ComHem<AF499A>"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC '3Webbkontakt-E0E4' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"3Webbkontakt-E0E4"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'TeliaGateway30-91-8F-2C-E4-53' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TeliaGateway30-91-8F-2C-E4-53"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'Pretty fly for a Wi-Fi' [AC5]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Pretty fly for a Wi-Fi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'TN_private_969E22' [AC6]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TN_private_969E22"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     3F8570547EE3A2BA3D5D734
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.2.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     7982686FBE8064A87E02753
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        54:4E:45:C0:BD:E6:F7:84:07:7A:BC:A3:DE:58:E4:8F:B5:25:EE:14
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[167274.593609] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and I just found the problem.
The 5Ghz network was setted to choose automatically the channel, one day it changed to a channel with an high number and my card wasn't able to find the network anymore.

So just check in your router if the network has an high number channel and change it back to a lower one (now I'm with channel 40 and it's working fine) and check if you can now find again the network.

I've also open a bug report in the bcmwl package page, if this is the problem click on the "This bug affect you" button in [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1574196)

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: That's a very likely cause, since the network also randomly came back one day; will remember this for the future, and I also clicked "affected" at that bug. Thanks!

Comment: It happened again, setting a channel manually did fix it, so now marking as accepted. Again, thanks!