# ASUS PCE cant detect 5ghz network

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, broadcom, asus

I have a wifi card with support for 5Ghz. The card is the [ASUS PCE AC56](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEAC56/specifications/).

I have installed the drivers for my WiFi card from the "Additions drivers" tab in "Software & Updates", using the "Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver".

I have set my router to give different SSIDs to the networks on 2.4Ghz and 5Ghzs.

When I go to my Wifi Settings and I list the visible networks, only the one on 2.4Ghz appear, but not the one with 5Ghz.

What would I have to do, to be able to find the 5Ghz network?

Comment: **:D** I was going to answer the exact same as is already answered and you've already accepted that answer ***but forgot to award the bounty...***  **;-)**

Comment: What do you mean? The bounty will be assigned to the accepted answer

Comment: No, it won't: if you don't manually award it, only half gets automatically awarded...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless lost ability to use 5GHz (PCE-AC68)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749420/wireless-lost-ability-to-use-5ghz-pce-ac68)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds the same as this problem: [Wireless lost ability to use 5GHz (PCE-AC68)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749420/wireless-lost-ability-to-use-5ghz-pce-ac68)

The answer there says:

> I had the same problem as you, and I just found the problem. The 5Ghz
>   network was set to choose automatically the channel, one day it
>   changed to a channel with an high number and my card wasn't able to
>   find the network anymore.
>
> So just check in your router if the network has an high number channel
>   and change it back to a lower one (now I'm with channel 40 and it's
>   working fine) and check if you can now find again the network.
>
> I've also open a bug report in the `bcmwl` package page, if this is the
>   problem click on the "This bug affect you" button in [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1574196)
>
> I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. I had never imagined that the channel would be a factor :-/

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Yes it is a weird bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1574196 Subscribe to the bug report to help get it fixed sooner.

Comment: Thanks bunch! Changing the channel # fixed my problem. Seems the Asus PCIe AC51 (in my case) is an old card that probably doesn't detect the high channels.